# Issue, iteration cross KV (NoSql/Redis) Target

Tags: python, redis, nosql, mlops, mlrun

I would like to iterated cross KV (NoSql,Redis) Target in MLRun without specification of primary key(s) also, but I saw only ability to get specific KV item(s) based on specific key(s). I have to use only unique items, not duplicit items.

I chose NoSql/Redis Target because key operations in-memory are critical for quick responce (based on specific key), but from time to time I have to iterate cross whole collection of keys (and it is case of this question).

You can see part of my code for getting values based on keys:

```
import mlrun 
import mlrun.feature_store as fs
...

svc=fs.get_online_feature_service(fs.FeatureVector("myVector", ["client.*"]))
resp = svc.get([{"cuid": 1926, "key1": 100023}])
```

Do you know, how to iterate cross items in KV (NoSql, Redis) target in MLRun CE/Paid editions (version 1.2.1)?

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: @D.L, do you see issues with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using these solutions for iteration cross keys in KV storage:

**1. NoSqlTarget**

Iteration via v3io (it is not pure part of MLRun API, but it is part of MLRun distribution packages). More information about v3io python SDK [see](https://github.com/v3io/v3io-py) and iteration cross KV items (cursor usage) [see sample](https://github.com/v3io/v3io-py#accessing-key-values-nosql)

```
import v3io.dataplane

v3io_client = v3io.dataplane.Client(endpoint='https://v3io-webapi:8081', access_key='some_access_key')

# create a query, and use an items cursor to iterate the results
items_cursor = v3io_client.kv.new_cursor(container='users',
                                         table_path='/user-profile',
                                         attribute_names=['income'],
                                         filter_expression='income > 150')

# print the output
for item in items_cursor.all():
    print(item)
```

BTW: NoSqlTarget is available only for MLRun Enterprise edition

**2. RedisTarget**

You can use easy iteration cross KV items, it is part of Redis API

```
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
for key in r.keys('*'):
    r.delete(key)
```

It is possible to use commandline also via `redis-cli` see sample:

```
redis-cli keys users*
```

or remove from redis specific keys based on list of keys:

```
redis-cli keys users* | xargs redis-cli del
```

BTW: RedisTarget is available for MLRun CE and Enterprise editions

Comment: Can you mention also redis-cli command?

Comment: Looks great thanks! Want to note that the V3IO option is only for Iguazio enterprise whereas the Redis option works on MLRun Community Edition

Comment: @JzD, I added sample from Redis

Answer (score 1):

The `NoSqlTarget` is using a KV store which is inherently for retrieving an individual value based on a given key. If you are looking to retrieve the entirety of your feature vector, you should use the offline store instead. More info in the MLRun docs [here](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/feature-store/feature-vectors.html#using-an-offline-feature-vector)

Alternatively, you could use the offline store to get a list of keys and then query the online store using those:

```py
import mlrun.feature_store as fstore

df = fstore.get_offline_features("my-vec").to_dataframe()
keys = list(resp.to_dataframe().index.unique())

svc = fstore.get_online_feature_service("my-vec")
svc.get([{"my-key" : key} for key in keys[:5]])
```

Comment: I have to use unique items (based on items rewriting) and based on that offline store such as parquet is not useful.

Comment: The ParquetTarget includes all records that have been ingested. This includes all versions of the items that you are writing. You can pass in a given time range to specify what you are looking for

Alternatively you can use offline store to get your list of keys to iterate over

Comment: Is it possible to iterate cross NoSqlTarget also?

Comment: No the KV source allows you to get one value for a given key. You need to provide the key for an efficient lookup. If you want a list of all the keys you can use the ParquetTarget and use that to iterate over

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do - not much to go off of in your question. If you provide a little more information on your use case there may be a better solution

Comment: I updated original question for better clarification.

Comment: My recommendation is the same

```python
import mlrun.feature_store as fstore

df = fstore.get_offline_features("my-vec").to_dataframe()

keys = list(resp.to_dataframe().index.unique())

svc = fstore.get_online_feature_service("my-vec")
svc.get([{"my-key" : key} for key in keys[:5]])
```

Comment: It is little overkill for me to keep whole history in parquet, but thanks for this useful solution. Please can you mention your solution directly in answer. If I understand it correctly, there is no chanse to iterate via NoSqlTarget (therefore Parquet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253039/discussion-between-nick-schenone-and-jzd).